# Import certain fields in Excel into Access based on field name -

Tags: excel, ms-access

I will be obtaining a few dozen MS Excel spreadsheets with 500+ columns and need to import just selected few columns into MS Access based on their column name.  I have no control over this and yes, there doesn't need to be that many columns.  I want to import a few selected fields only.  In particular, I only want to import columns that have "c_" in the column name.  The problem is I can't figure out how to do this.  The other problem is the number of columns will vary each time, but I will always need the columns that start with "c_".

Normally when I use VBA code to import Excel data, it's not too difficult for me if I have to select a range. For example:

`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "ards_data_new", "H:\Misc. Projects\ARDS project\ards_data.xlsx", True, "ards_data!A1:A50"`

The problem is that the range will vary for each file, so I can't do it this way.  I wish there was a way I could use the command Like "*c_*" in obtaining the columns I need only, but I just don't know how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use Excel Automation objects to open and inspect spreadsheet directly before import.  How about a temporary import table into which you just get everything and then use VBA to inspect the import table and generate an append or make-table query to get just the columns you need?  Perhaps better yet is to link to the spreadsheet so SQL queries can be executed directly on the data. Really there are many ways to approach this. BTW, your example shows that you only import one column.

Comment: The only thing is that the column names will change each time, but the "c_" will always remain consistent however.  I am hoping to automate as much of this as I can since I'll have to do this with 50+ spreadsheets over the course of time.  I'd prefer not to have to change my SQL code or linkage each time. I realize I will have to change the filename each time, but that's less of a concern and much less work.

Comment: More to the point:  Provide example data, including source columns and the destination table into which the data should go.  Otherwise the given description is really not sufficient to offer help beyond what I've suggested.

Comment: Built-in data bindings, including SQL queries, are based on static column names.  There is *no built-in or automatic* mechanism for handling varying number of columns between imports, nor a mechanism for handling column names that only match a pattern.  The solution is the programmability of the process, using VBA, macros, etc.  The **overall process is possible**, *but the desire to setup unchanging SQL or "linkage" is not realistic*, since the requirements given in the question demand that you program a dynamic solution to correctly identify the columns and map them into the database.

Comment: However, it does not mean that you cannot program something that will efficiently handle the situation.  It does not mean that the process must remain a manual, fluctuating system.  On the contrary, once you correctly identify and program appropriate rules to handle the various import locations and column names, the system could in that sense become as you desire "not to have to change... each time".